# Preinit is same as other events?

Tags: asp.net

**[PreInit](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1512/aspnet-page-life-cycle-events/)** The entry point of the page life cycle is the pre-initialization phase called “PreInit”. This is the only event where programmatic access to master pages and themes is allowed. You can dynamically set the values of master pages and themes in this event. You can also dynamically create controls in this event.

But this definition is valid for other events like load init etc. Correct?

I meant, this job can be done in other events as well.

**Query** What's the unique meaning of PreInit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there can be overlaps depending on what you're doing, but it's good practice to stick with the actual ASP.NET page life cycle and use the correct events. There is a good breakdown on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) of each event's actions.

`Init` for example is raised after the controls have been created, so any dynamic changes won't take effect immediately.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by unique meaning, but the link shows you the various actions recommended in the section. By setting values there, you then have access to the new values in the later events. Why the downvote?

Comment: this [link also give the idea](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1512/aspnet-page-life-cycle-events/). But how to uniquely differentiate PreInit with other events ?

Comment: Would be nice if the downvoters actually explained what's wrong with the answer so that it can be improved.

Comment: @Needhelp Do you mean how to handle it? Or how is it different? It's just an early event you can handle if you need to make the changes listed in the link. You can still perform certain actions in other events if you prefer, but the data you have later on may not be the same. For example, you don't have ViewState data in PreInit, but you do in the Loaded event.

Comment: can you kindly provide an explain that explains specific usage of Preinit and that same usage does not fit properly in other events or not useful in other event?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21731/discussion-between-needhelp-and-keyboardp)

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can add really. The link I've given in the answer explains what Microsoft recommends you do in the `PreInit` event. Maybe someone else can answer your question better, but just because you can access something from another event, doesn't mean it's a good idea. If tomorrow the implementation of ASP.NET page cycles changes, however unlikely, and you've followed the guidelines, then you can be confident that your site will likely continue to work.

Comment: I already know the details actually. I was actually looking for some knowledge which like only PreInit is competent to do. Like it's loop hole is - we cannot find the memory of controls in user control?